# How to copy paste pivot table values?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My macro is supposed to copy paste all visible rows of data into Outlook mail. It works for another sheet but it's not working when I try it on a pivot table.

These are my codes and my current output in Outlook.

It works for another sheet in my Excel file which copy pastes all visible data into Outlook directly.

[image: ![image](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)]

```
Option Base 1
Private i As Integer, LastRowI As Integer, LastRowII As Integer, t As Integer
Private MCells As Range, CCells As Range
Private rng As Range
Private count As Integer
Private Arr() As String


Sub ExportMail()

count = 0

Dim myOutApp As Object
Dim myOutmail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim text, address, addressCC, subject, Name As String
Dim lastrow, vArrayLength, i, counter, t, x As Integer

'Create array using CBF values
    lastrow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp"
    Worksheets(2).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastrow, 2)).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Rows(1).Delete Shift:=x1Up
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Range("$A$1:$A$" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    
    ReDim Arr(0 To lastrow)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(i, 1)
            Debug.Print "The value " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(i, 1) & " has been assigned to the " & i & ". element of the array"
        Next i
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set CCells = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    
 For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
    Set MCells = Nothing
    Set MCells = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
        For Each rng In CCells
            If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(rng.Row, 7) = Arr(i) Then
                Set MCells = Union(MCells, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(rng.Row, 1), ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(rng.Row, 7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            End If
        Next rng
        Debug.Print MCells.address
        
        Set findcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Columns("D").Find(Arr(i))
        If Not findcell Is Nothing Then
        address = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(findcell.Row, 5)
        If LCase(Left(address, 10)) = "fixed-term" Then
            Name = Right(address, Len(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EMail").Cells(2, 2)) - InStr(1, address, "."))
            Name = Left(Name, InStr(1, Name, ".") - 1)
            Name = UCase(Left(Name, 1)) & Right(Name, Len(Name) - 1)
                Else
            Name = Left(address, InStr(1, address, ".") - 1)
            Name = UCase(Left(Name, 1)) & Right(Name, Len(Name) - 1)
        End If
        Else
        MsgBox "There is no Match for " & Arr(i)
        End If
        
            
        subject = Left(SheetValue, 4) & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EMail").Cells(4, 2)
        addressCC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EMail").Cells(3, 2)
        lastrow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$Z" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print rng.address
        
        Header = RangetoHTML(MCells)
              
        text = "<font style=""font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;"">" & _
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EMail").Cells(1, 2) & "</font>" & vbNewLine
            
        text = Replace(text, "NAME", Name)
           
        text = Replace(text, "_PartNumbers_", Header)
        
        
        Set myOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MyMessage = myOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With MyMessage
            .GetInspector.Display
            .To = address
            .CC = addressCC
            .subject = subject
            Signature = MyMessage.htmlbody
            .htmlbody = text & Signature
        End With
        Set myOutApp = Nothing
        Set MyMessage = Nothing
    Next i
    
        
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(MCells As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    MCells.Copy
    
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    TempWB.Sheets(1).Activate
    
 With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    
    Kill TempFile
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

    
End Function
```

Comment: What is the output of your text string? Did you try to debug the code and compare results?

Comment: Make sure that you get a well-formed HTML markup as an end result.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The text string is replaced with the values of Name and Header which works correctly. The code works, it just doesn't copy my entire table but only the header as shown in my screenshot. However, it works perfectly fine in another sheet within the same file which got me confused.